# Alternative to Windows FTP client

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

We have a legacy system that uses the Windows FTP client with some FTP script files to manipulate files over FTP.  We've found the Windows FTP client to be fairly unreliable though in regards to error handling - for example if it can't connect to the remote site it doesn't even return an error code from the commandline. And sometimes it just seems to hang altogether if the connection to the FTP server goes down midway through a file transfer.

So we're looking for an alternative. Is there a script-able commandline FTP client for Windows that will handle the existing FTP script files (written for the Windows FTP client) out of the box, but with improved error handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up "MOVEit Freely".  It's primary role is a drop-in replacement for ftp.exe to handle FTP/S, but it may also have the better behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your activities are surrounding your FTP usage, but if it's a build web app local and deploy to server type activities, you could try CruiseControl: http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/

This might be a good replacement for FTP scripts if you're concerned about error handling.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've used and loved cruisecontrol  in the past.  Unfortunately in this case it's a legacy system, and FTP is used for a b2b type scenario; invoked from SQL Agent, though that's not really important for the question;  but we're looking for a tool that can drop in place of the built in windows ftp client.